# How can I compute the Gaussian curvature without using the fact that $K=\frac{\det(II)}{\det(I)}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I am given a regular surface $S$ with orientation $N$ and a parametrization of the entire surface $\phi:U 
\subset_{open} \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S$. How can I compute the Gaussian curvature without using the fact that $K=\frac{\det(II)}{\det(I)}$? It seems I can only compute $K$ as being the determinant of the differential of the Gauss map.

I know I can compute $N_u,N_v$, but where do I go to compute the 2x2 matrix $dN_p$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $N\cdot N=1$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(N\cdot N)=0$ and
similar for $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}(N\cdot N)=0$.

But 
$\frac{\partial N}{\partial v}\cdot N+N\cdot\frac{\partial N}{\partial v}=2\frac{\partial N}{\partial v}\cdot N=0$ as well $2\frac{\partial N}{\partial w}\cdot N=0$.

Then $N_v, N_w$ are perpendicular to $N$, so
they are tangential and there exists scalars $A,B,C,D$ such that
$$N_v=A\partial_v+B\partial_w\qquad{\rm  
and}\qquad N_w=C\partial_v+D\partial_w.$$
Hence 
$$K_{\rm Gauss}=AD-BC.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, use [the Brioschi formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrioschiFormula.html) that uses only the first fundamental form and its derivatives.